# CSS - 100% height doesn't expand to content

Tags: css

I have previously posted another question about this, but it was hard for me to explain without a JSfiddle. I have just spent about 20 minutes doing this fiddle!

http://jsfiddle.net/4AYyX/9/

I have expandable DIV's so the "container" needs to stretch to the length of the expanded div's. The problem is that when the div's are expanded, the content disappears off the bottom of the page, instead of stretching the page. I have tried adding padding etc, but nothing seems to work.

The JS fiddle linked above is the issue I am having.

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
#wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

**UPDATED FIDDLE PLEASE CHECK AGAIN**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is 'Footer text' dosen't stretch within the rest of the body? So try to delete height property in #wrapper tag:

```
#wrapper {
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

Comment: The problem was that I had overflow hidden. The footer isn't a problem. The problem now is that the page expands, but the container doesn't. http://cis.kitoit.com/feedbackreview/

Comment: Container expands too. Problem is the border right? Just put the `<div id="border_line"></div>` inside div#col1 instead of div#col2. And add some bottom padding at the bottom of div#col1 (eg 40px).

Comment: No. The problem is that the main container around the site does not expand. Thanks for trying.

Comment: Then add a `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` at the end of `div#container`. You should also delete `top:120px` property from `div#col1` and add a `margin-top:120px` instead. Maybe some other little fixes may do the trick

Comment: That makes it work a bit better thanks, But still the main issue is that the page does not expand when the arrows are clicked to expand the section. The expanded sections simply run off of the bottom. If you click the red arrows on the link, you will see this. cis.kitoit.com/feedbackreview

Comment: So, delete `height: 800px;` from `div#col1`! Do not fix height if you want it to be stretched. Delete it and it'll work like a charm...

Answer (score 1):

Try `min-height: 100%;` instead.

Comment: Seems to work on the fiddle.. just not on my live page.

Answer (score 1):

You need to delete `padding-bottom` and `margin-bottom` on the `#container` div

See this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4AYyX/10/)**

margin and padding are added to the 100% height so it stetches the content down.
you can also use the `box-sizing` property see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp)

Comment: That is not the problem I am having. The problem is that it doesn't strech.

Answer (score 1):

Some small style mistakes, just do correction like below i mentioned.

Footer position style shouldn't be absoulte, and container overflow shouldn't be hidden.
and you're good to go

and some other lil things need to corrected

```
#footer {
    bottom:0; //removed position style
}

#container {
    position: relative; //overflow removed
    top: 5px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(159, 159, 159, 0.6);
    -o-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(159, 159, 159, 0.6);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(159, 159, 159, 0.6);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(159, 159, 159, 0.6);
    padding-bottom:150px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The overflow was the issue. Except that now, the page expands, but the container doesn't. http://cis.kitoit.com/feedbackreview/